# React JS: Cannot get input from user, get undefined when typing

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, ethereum, solidity

I am writing an app so that a user can fill in a registration form and then it will be shown the name and other parameters of this person using React JS, all of this also coming from a Smart Contract. I am getting the problem of having undefined inputs after typing into the text inputs and I suspect it has something to do with the state, but not sure how to fix it.

Here is the code for the Parent code, called App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import dxclogo from './dxclogo.png';
import './App.css';
import Web3 from 'web3';
import _ from 'lodash'
import { Form } from './Form';

//Declaring the ethereum client (initializing) with the url in which the testrpc is running
var ETHEREUM_CLIENT = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"))

//These could be dynamically added through input fields, but hard coding for now
var peopleContractABI = [{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getPeople","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bytes32[]"},{"name":"","type":"bytes32[]"},{"name":"","type":"bytes32[]"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"name":"people","outputs":[{"name":"firstName","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"lastName","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"age","type":"bytes32"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_firstName","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"_lastName","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"_age","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"addPerson","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"}]

var peopleContractAddress = '0x7d58e54b812b1f7c5c47f0a85af5f9f6a1d3f5c8'

var peopleContract = ETHEREUM_CLIENT.eth.contract(peopleContractABI).at(peopleContractAddress)

class App extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      firstNames: [],
      lastNames: [],
      ages: []
    }
  }

  componentWillMount(){
    var data = peopleContract.getPeople()
    this.setState({
      firstNames: String(data[0]).split(','),
      lastNames: String(data[1]).split(','),
      ages: String(data[2]).split(',')
    })
  }

  render() {
    var TableRows = []

    _.each(this.state.firstNames, (value, index) => {
    TableRows.push(
      <tr>
        <td>{ETHEREUM_CLIENT.toAscii(this.state.firstNames[index])}</td>
        <td>{ETHEREUM_CLIENT.toAscii(this.state.lastNames[index])}</td>
        <td>{ETHEREUM_CLIENT.toAscii(this.state.ages[index])}</td>
      </tr>
    )
  })

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <img src = {dxclogo} className ="App-dxclogo" alt="dxclogo" />
          <h1>Hotel Room Booking dApp</h1>
        </div>
        <div>
          <Form />
          <table className="App-tablePeople">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>First Name </th>
                <th>Last Name </th>
                <th>Age </th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {TableRows}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Child code, called Form.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Web3 from 'web3';

//Declaring the ethereum client (initializing) with the url in which the testrpc is running
var ETHEREUM_CLIENT = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"))

//These could be dynamically added through input fields, but hard coding for now
var peopleContractABI = [{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getPeople","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bytes32[]"},{"name":"","type":"bytes32[]"},{"name":"","type":"bytes32[]"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"name":"people","outputs":[{"name":"firstName","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"lastName","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"age","type":"bytes32"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_firstName","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"_lastName","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"_age","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"addPerson","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"}]

var peopleContractAddress = '0x7d58e54b812b1f7c5c47f0a85af5f9f6a1d3f5c8'

var peopleContract = ETHEREUM_CLIENT.eth.contract(peopleContractABI).at(peopleContractAddress)

//Need to create a variable named accounts in order to know which account
//to make the transactions from
var accounts = ETHEREUM_CLIENT.eth.accounts

//Creating the dynamic input fields for the user to input his/her data
export class Form extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    age: "",
  }

  this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({firstName: event.target.firstName});
    this.setState({lastName: event.target.lastName});
    this.setState({age: event.target.age});

  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('A user was submitted: ' + this.state.firstName + this.state.lastName + this.state.age);
    event.preventdefault();
  }


//Creating so that person can be added
  componentWillMount(){
     peopleContract.addPerson(this.state.firstName, this.state.lastName, this.state.age, {from: accounts[1], gas: 3000000})
    }

  render() {
    return(
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
      <h4>Name</h4>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Name, e.g. Javier"
          firstName={this.state.firstName}
          onChange={this.handleChange}  />
        <div>
        <h4>Last Name</h4>
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Last Name, e.g. Hernandez"
            lastName={this.state.lastName}
            onChange={this.handleChange}/>
        </div>
        <div>
        <h4>Age</h4>
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Age, e.g. 35"
            age={this.state.age}
            onChange={this.handleChange}/>
        </div>
        <input
          type = "submit"
          name = "Submit"
          />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: what's `event.target.firstName` supposed to be? I think you mean `event.target.value`

Comment: `firstName` is meant to be the same as `value` in code, or that is what I have thought

Comment: `event.target` is referring to the DOM node, which does not have a `firstName` property. use `event.target.value` and you will see the values coming in

Comment: You may also append your `handleChange` function to take an extra argument, the state key. if that works for you I can write up an answer

Comment: Yes, that could work. If you can write a solution I would appreciate it

Comment: The issue I am having as well is that I need the text the user will write to be inserted into `peopleContract.addPerson(this.state.firstName, this.state.lastName, this.state.age, {from: accounts[1], gas: 3000000})` as the three parameters that I am trying to insert using the state

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track, but your `handleChange` function is a little too hardcoded. Take more parameters, such that it's generalized for any input:

```
handleChange(event, key) {
  this.setState({ [key]: event.target.value })
}
```

Update your `onChange` handlers to pass that info along:

```
<input
  type="text"
  placeholder="Name, e.g. Javier"
  firstName={this.state.firstName}
  onChange={event => this.handleChange(event, 'firstName')}  
/>
```

and so forth for the rest of your inputs. Then you could submit and your form will contain all the necessary state. If not, you can do some validation there.

Comment: This now works but I am getting individual letters, instead of the whole word. I change so that I have the `peopleContract.addPerson` function inside render like `render() {
    peopleContract.addPerson(this.state.firstName, this.state.lastName, this.state.age, {from: accounts[1], gas: 3000000})
    return(`

Comment: where are you getting individual letters?

Comment: can you update your question with the newest code please

Answer (score 0):

Here is the latest code. I am getting individual letters when outputting the text in the localhost web using

```
componentWillMount(){
    var data = peopleContract.getPeople()
    this.setState({
      firstNames: String(data[0]).split(','),
      lastNames: String(data[1]).split(','),
      ages: String(data[2]).split(',')
    })
  }

  render() {
    var TableRows = []

    _.each(this.state.firstNames, (value, index) => {
    TableRows.push(
      <tr>
        <td>{ETHEREUM_CLIENT.toAscii(this.state.firstNames[index])}</td>
        <td>{ETHEREUM_CLIENT.toAscii(this.state.lastNames[index])}</td>
        <td>{ETHEREUM_CLIENT.toAscii(this.state.ages[index])}</td>
      </tr>
    )
  })
```

Either way, the newest code is this:

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import dxclogo from './dxclogo.png';
import './App.css';
import Web3 from 'web3';
import _ from 'lodash'
import { Form } from './Form';

//Declaring the ethereum client (initializing) with the url in which the testrpc is running
var ETHEREUM_CLIENT = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"))

//These could be dynamically added through input fields, but hard coding for now
var peopleContractABI = [{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getPeople","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bytes32[]"},{"name":"","type":"bytes32[]"},{"name":"","type":"bytes32[]"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"name":"people","outputs":[{"name":"firstName","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"lastName","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"age","type":"bytes32"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_firstName","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"_lastName","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"_age","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"addPerson","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"}]

var peopleContractAddress = '0x6c6a4a3e14e25a31fcc323aed7e8395a7df56a6f'

var peopleContract = ETHEREUM_CLIENT.eth.contract(peopleContractABI).at(peopleContractAddress)

class App extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      firstNames: [],
      lastNames: [],
      ages: []
    }
  }

  componentWillMount(){
    var data = peopleContract.getPeople()
    this.setState({
      firstNames: String(data[0]).split(','),
      lastNames: String(data[1]).split(','),
      ages: String(data[2]).split(',')
    })
  }

  render() {
    var TableRows = []

    _.each(this.state.firstNames, (value, index) => {
    TableRows.push(
      <tr>
        <td>{ETHEREUM_CLIENT.toAscii(this.state.firstNames[index])}</td>
        <td>{ETHEREUM_CLIENT.toAscii(this.state.lastNames[index])}</td>
        <td>{ETHEREUM_CLIENT.toAscii(this.state.ages[index])}</td>
      </tr>
    )
  })

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <img src = {dxclogo} className ="App-dxclogo" alt="dxclogo" />
          <h1>Hotel Room Booking dApp</h1>
        </div>
        <div>
          <Form />
          <table className="App-tablePeople">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>First Name </th>
                <th>Last Name </th>
                <th>Age </th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {TableRows}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**Form.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Web3 from 'web3';

//Declaring the ethereum client (initializing) with the url in which the testrpc is running
var ETHEREUM_CLIENT = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"))

//These could be dynamically added through input fields, but hard coding for now
var peopleContractABI = [{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getPeople","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bytes32[]"},{"name":"","type":"bytes32[]"},{"name":"","type":"bytes32[]"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"name":"people","outputs":[{"name":"firstName","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"lastName","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"age","type":"bytes32"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_firstName","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"_lastName","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"_age","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"addPerson","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"}]

var peopleContractAddress = '0x6c6a4a3e14e25a31fcc323aed7e8395a7df56a6f'

var peopleContract = ETHEREUM_CLIENT.eth.contract(peopleContractABI).at(peopleContractAddress)

//Need to create a variable named accounts in order to know which account
//to make the transactions from
var accounts = ETHEREUM_CLIENT.eth.accounts

//Creating the dynamic input fields for the user to input his/her data
export class Form extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    firstName: 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000,
    lastName: 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000,
    age: 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000,
  }

  this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event, key) {
    this.setState({[key]: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('A user was submitted: ' + this.state.firstName + this.state.lastName + this.state.age);
    event.preventdefault();
  }


/*Creating so that person can be added
  componentWillMount(){
     peopleContract.addPerson(this.state.firstName, this.state.lastName, this.state.age, {from: accounts[1], gas: 3000000})
    }
    */

  render() {
    peopleContract.addPerson(this.state.firstName, this.state.lastName, this.state.age, {from: accounts[1], gas: 3000000})
    return(
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
      <h4>Name</h4>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Name, e.g. Javier"
          value={this.state.firstName}
          onChange={event => this.handleChange(event, 'firstName')}  />
        <div>
        <h4>Last Name</h4>
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Last Name, e.g. Hernandez"
            value={this.state.lastName}
            onChange={event => this.handleChange(event, 'lastName')}/>
        </div>
        <div>
        <h4>Age</h4>
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Age, e.g. 35"
            value={this.state.age}
            name="age"
            onChange={event => this.handleChange(event, 'age')}/>
        </div>
        <input
          type = "submit"
          name = "Submit"
          />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```